# Errors while running Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on my laptop. 
Since the time of installation I have been facing a few issues.
I was not able to even access the New Project option itself.
Some of the times I will be able to access it however, sometimes it does not even allow me to access a single file of my solution in the startup itself it gives me an error.

I have attached a set of five screenshots in this query. There is some blank space after users path, I removed an extra folder name(username) from the path so dont get confused with that.
The detail of all the screenshots are as follows:

1) This is the image I get when I launch the Visual Studio on my laptop.
2) Once I click 'NO' option on the first dialog box I get a new one stating an error with the source code.
3) Once that is done, I move onto Solution Explorer to access the solution and I get this log.
4) When I try to access the tools tab to check for options I get this error message.
5) I had even tried to create a new project and the following error provided in this screenshot would appear.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuZpr.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UteBE.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl7tV.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMOGJ.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4QMO.png]

I am not able to understand where I could have gone wrong or what happened that has corrupted the application to this extent. Is it an installation issue or are there some bugs in this version of Visual Studio, if there are any I would be more than happy to move to previous versions as I was a lot happier with them than this one.

If someone would help on this concern I would be really thankful.

Regards,
Harrisson

Comment: I've loaded and successfully used VS 2015 Community Edition.  I'd suggest you remove VS 2015 and reinstall.

Comment: I have tried it twice already and I have removed the corresponding files related to VS 2015 and still I am getting this error. Also, I have installed VS 2015 Community Edition on 2 devices and it is working fine on the other device.

Comment: Well, I had expected atleast one response to my question as I thought it was a genuine case and it might have occurred before. However, I dont think anyone has come up with this issue so far. I have posted the method I used to rectify this concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I went ahead and uninstalled the current version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 from my system. Then, I searched and removed the data from the temporary files related to MS VS 2015 from the following paths:
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
Once this had been done, I went ahead and installed Visual Studio 2015. After installation, I installed the additional support directories for Visual C++. You can do the same for the platform you wish to work on.
Then I installed updates from the following link:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs
Once I started the solution it worked perfectly fine after that with no errors.